# Using Django,I want my user when he Register ,He directly go to to create page, But when I do it ,It never go to create page .Here is my code

Tags: django, django-registration, django-url-reverse

Views.py

```
#For Cystomer Registration
class CustomerRegistrationView(View):
 def get(self,request):
   form = CustomerRegistrationForm()
   return render(request,'mp/register.html',{'form':form})
 def post(self,request):
   form = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
   
   if form.is_valid():
    messages.success(request,'Congratulations Registerd Succesfuly ')
    form.save()
    
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
   
   return render(request,'mp/register.html',{'form':form})

#For Creating Profile
class ProfileCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):#ye hogia hamara upload wala
model = Profile
fields = ['user_name','user_ethnicity','SelectGender','user_job','user_age','mother_additionalinfo']
success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profilecreate')
    return super(ProfileCreate,self).form_valid(form)
```

Urls.py

```
#for register
     path('register/',views.CustomerRegistrationView.as_view(),name= 'register'),
#for CreateProfile
     path('profilecreate/',views.ProfileCreate.as_view(),name= 'profilecreate'),
```

Also the Important thing is that when i have not setup the Logout Function  then it working,But when i steup,Then this not redirect user to another page and stay at Registration Page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **redirect** instead, so that will be something like the below

```
return redirect("profilecreate")
```

Also another that i noticed is that your ProfileCreate doesnt to be a **View** i cant see any **post** or **get** function, if this will be a page you should add a function, in your case a **post** function.

Comment: Sir, Now when User Created, It give me an error of Page No Found With This Url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/profilecreate/. It does not go to Profile Create View because it is not logged in but just Registered. And I want the User Go to Profilecreateview  only one time. Later he can Update it.

Comment: can you show the updated code please

Comment: also try to go to that 'profilecreate' url on your own to see if that url is working on its own, if not try make it work on its own